# Combine results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to query DNN and get two PropertyDefinitionID's and two the values for each PropertyDefinitionID. This is the code I am using right now but doesn't return any results.

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_Users u
INNER JOIN UserRoles r ON u.UserID = r.UserID and r.RoleID = '4'
INNER JOIN UserProfile p ON u.UserID = p.UserID
WHERE (p.PropertyValue = 'b510dab0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c' AND
       p.PropertyDefinitionID = '47') AND
      (p.PropertyValue = 'True' AND
       p.PropertyDefinitionID = '48')
ORDER BY p.PropertyValue
```

There is a record with a PropertyDefinitionID = 47 and PropertyValue = 'b510dab0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c'. And there is also a record with PropertyDefinitionID = 48 and PropertyValue = 'True'.

So if I broke this query apart I would get this for the first one:

```
UserId  PropertyDefinitionID     PropertyValue
5   47                   eb03dde0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c
```

and this for the second one:

```
UserId  PropertyDefinitionID     PropertyValue
5   48                   True
```

But I would like them to be in one Query or at least the results be combined. Is this possible? And if so how in the world do you do it?

EDIT: But I only want to return the result if it has a Value for PropertyDefinitionID = 47 and only if PropertyDefinitionID = 48 is true. I want both criteria to meet.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `) OR (` instead of `) AND (`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE (p.PropertyValue = 'b510dab0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c' AND
       p.PropertyDefinitionID = '47') OR /*<------------------- Changed*/
      (p.PropertyValue = 'True' AND
       p.PropertyDefinitionID = '48')
```

In response to the comments. To get users meeting both criteria you can use.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   vw_Users u
       INNER JOIN UserRoles r
         ON u.UserID = r.UserID
WHERE  r.RoleID = '4'
       AND u.UserId IN (SELECT UserID
                        FROM   UserProfile
                        WHERE  ( PropertyValue =
                                 'b510dab0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c'
                                 AND PropertyDefinitionID = '47' )
                                OR 
                               ( PropertyValue = 'True'
                                 AND PropertyDefinitionID = '48' )
                        GROUP  BY UserID
                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PropertyDefinitionID) = 2)
```

It should be clear how to extend this for an arbitrary number of conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I only want to return the result if it has a Value for PropertyDefinitionID = 47 and only if PropertyDefinitionID = 48 is true. I want both criteria to meet.

Answer (score 2):

You are using AND for everything. You should use OR to separate your conditions. Like in logic classes: AND is to intersection what OR is for union.

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_Users u
INNER JOIN UserRoles r ON u.UserID = r.UserID and r.RoleID = '4'
INNER JOIN UserProfile p ON u.UserID = p.UserID
WHERE (p.PropertyValue = 'b510dab0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c' AND p.PropertyDefinitionID = '47') OR
      (p.PropertyValue = 'True' AND p.PropertyDefinitionID = '48')
ORDER BY p.PropertyValue
```

Answer (score 1):

**INNER JOIN the UserProfile table twice** (see modified code). 
Once for the PropertyDefinitionID = '47' conditions
Again for PropertyDefinitionID = '48' conditions

I would also change the SELECT * to only the select the ***specific fields*** you want returned

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM       vw_Users u 
INNER JOIN UserRoles r 
        ON u.UserID = r.UserID 
       and r.RoleID = '4' 
INNER JOIN UserProfile p1 
        ON u.UserID = p1.UserID 
       and p1.PropertyValue = 'b510dab0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c'
       and p1.PropertyDefinitionID = '47'
INNER JOIN UserProfile p2 
        ON u.UserID = p2.UserID 
       and p2.PropertyValue = True
       and p2.PropertyDefinitionID = '48'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change one of the `AND` statements to an `OR`, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM vw_Users u
INNER JOIN UserRoles r ON u.UserID = r.UserID and r.RoleID = '4'
INNER JOIN UserProfile p ON u.UserID = p.UserID
WHERE (p.PropertyValue = 'b510dab0-8bf6-e011-84a9-00505691002c' AND

       p.PropertyDefinitionID = '47') OR    --HERE'S YOUR PROBLEM

      (p.PropertyValue = 'True' AND
       p.PropertyDefinitionID = '48')
ORDER BY p.PropertyValue
```